# grep on colored lines

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I wrote a simple PHP shell script which parses files and outputs certain element.
It generates lots of output. In different (bash) colors, green for OK, yellow for warnings, red for errors, etc.

During development I want to filter some lines out. For example all lines that contains red text.

Can I use a `grep` (or other) command for this?

Comment: Sample input / output would be good here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what your input looks like, but as a proof of concept you can filter any lines in `ls` output that use green colour:

```
ls --color=always | grep '^[\[01;32m'
```

The lookup table for other colours can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

**Hint**: In case you didn't know, the `^[` part above should be entered like <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> (or indeed <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> on most terminals).
*I'm sure there will be some option to grep to make it understand `\x1B` instead, but I haven't found it*

Comment: This excellent article comes to mind. Why you never should parse the output of ls http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
No objections to your answer, which is a good one!

Comment: I knew it :) Someone was going to say something about my bad-ass attempt at forcing colorful ouput. In this case, it is entirely ok to do so, because the objective is to show lines containing the ANSI escape for _green_. No presumption _whatsoever_ on the source of said lines, let alone any meaning. The definition of a line is quite widely accepted in a UNIX filter context :)

Comment: Here are some alternatives instead of using `ctrl+V, ESC`: `grep $'^\e\[31m'`, `grep $'^\033\[31m'`, `grep -P '^\e\[31m'`, `grep -P '^\033\[31m'`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you parse the input once to colorize it anyway, right? Why not 'cut out' warnings/errors in the same function? Make your script use command line options, like `myscript --nowarnings`

There is `getopt` for PHP tutorial [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/command-line-arguments-php-cli/)

I don't know any php, but something like (pseudocode):

```
paintred(string, show){
    match(string);
    if(show){
        print(string) in red;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Where `show` would depend on command line option.

This way you only parse the file once, and you give the future users an option to skip OK lines or warnings.