# git diff output only changed lines

Tags: git

If I run `git diff` I get this

```
diff --git a/README b/README
index 8d78ee4..67451cd 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 dog
-cat
+fox
 bird
```

However I only want this

```
-cat
+fox
```

I ended up using this

```sh
git diff --color | awk '/^\033\[3[12]m/'
```

Comment: out of curiousity: why do you only want the changed lines without any context? If you have multiple changed lines, things will become complicated....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on my system:

```sh
git diff --color | grep -P '\e\[3[12]m'
```

It uses color output to differentiate those lines.  By searching for the green and red color markers it should only print the added and removed lines.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278067/3025921) may help to understand the color aspect more if you need to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-U` or `--unified` flag to specify how much context to show.

```
-U<n>, --unified=<n>
    Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies -p.
```

You want `-U0`, or `--unified=0`.

As far as I know git doesn't provide a way to suppress the header.

Comment: That's only a partial answer. For the OP's example, that will suppress two lines out of the seven asked to suppress.

Answer (score 0):

sed

```sh
git diff | sed '/^i/{N;N};/^[-+]/b;d'
```

awk

```sh
git diff | awk '/^i/{c=NR}NR>c+2&&/^[-+]/'
```

With both solutions:

1. Filter out `+++` and `---` lines
2. Filter in added and removed lines